# Data crashes when I try to convert a bytearray to String in Kotlin

Tags: android

I have bytearray [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 127, 7, -120, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] when I try to convert it to String
I got this ������������������������� result in koltin, I tried several methods to convert it still no luck

I tried this line of code
`Log.d("Data", String(cardNumber!!))`
and this
`Log.d("Data", cardNumber!!.toString())`

Comment: What text data do you *expect* that byte array to represent, and where does it come from?

Comment: I expect something like this:  "268200000002003" card number in string formate

Comment: Show your code to begin with.

Comment: this data is coming from MiFare classic card block previously written from card initializer

Comment: @blackapps ` val cardNumber = standardBus?.callReadOneSectorDataFromCard(
                  piccType,
                  cardNumberBlk,
                  key,
                  serialNo
                )` 
this method returns me this byteArray
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 127, 7, -120, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: Why would you expect that byte array to map to that string? I don't see any correlation between the two. Fundamentally, it looks like that data *isn't textual data*.

Comment: Please put your code in your post. Not afterwards in a comment. Write a decent post.